# How to merge two formulas in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

How can I merge these two formulas in one cell?

```
= IF(D2="TRUE",C2+C2*20%, C2)

= IF(E2="TRUE",C2+30000, C2)
```

I have created two dropdown menu in excel, but can't merge them together.

I have tried to use this `= IF(E2="TRUE",C2+30000, C2, IF(E2="TRUE",C2+30000, C2))`, but it didn't work. Error:

> you have entered too many arguments for this function.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `=IF(D2="TRUE",C2+C2*20%,  IF(E2="TRUE",C2+30000, C2))`

Comment: Thank you, Scott.

Answer (score 0):

=IF(D2="TRUE",C2+C2*20%,  IF(E2="TRUE",C2+30000, C2))

Answered by @ScottCraner in the comments.